# Inconsistent behavior with String removingPercentEncoding:

Tags: linux, swift, swift3, ibm-swift-sandbox

I am seeing inconsistent behavior with the open source release of Swift 3 compared with the version that shipped with Xcode 8 with the String instance method `removingPercentEncoding`:

```
let testString = "valid àæ"
let escapedString = testString.removingPercentEncoding
```

In Xcode, the result of `escapedString` is `"valid àæ"`.  However the open source version of Swift returns `"valid à"` (missing `æ`).

[Try it online.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5810e05f71e7057b723e5cef)

What am I missing?

Comment: It's worth noting that the IBM Swift Sandbox is running the Linux version of Swift, which is a different implementation from the Xcode version. So it's more likely to be a "Linux vs. MacOS" thing than an "Xcode vs. open source" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug where `CFStringGetLength` would return an incorrect value for non-latin characters.  `_CFStringCreateByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` and `_CFStringCreateByRemovingPercentEncoding` are now fixed.

[SR-3052](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3052)

[Foundation PR #706](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/pull/706)